# Adding integers from a file

Tags: python

I'm writing a function that sums up integers from a file.
Here's the code:

```
def sum_integers_from_file(file_name):
    try:
       file = open(name)
       total = 0
       for i in file:
           total += int(i)
       file.close()
       return total
    except:
       print "error"
```

file `foo.txt`:

> 1234

The function returns `1234`.

why doesn't `total += int(i)` add up all the integers?

Comment: Please fix your indentation!

Comment: since your file has no newlines, and you're not splitting by character, the calculation is 0 + 1234

Comment: `for i in file` iterates over the lines of text in the file, not the chars. PS, open files with a `with` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is highly recommended to read files in a `with` statement. That frees you from the responsibility of closing the file and is also shorter! This works:

```
def sum_integers_from_file(file_name):
    try:
        with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
            s = f.read()

        total = 0
        for char in s:
            total += int(char)
        return total
    except:
        print("error")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your file has one line.

You're adding all ints from each line.

If you want to add 1,2,3,4 with that method move them to new lines

Also, you can do the same thing with this

```
   with open(name) as f:
       return sum(int(line) for line in f)
```

Comment: No the author does not need to do that. Each digit/char can be interpreted as an integer...

Comment: The question was asking why that's returned. Never gave what's expected

Comment: Ok, fair enough.